# rsnapshot LVM without root

Tags: sudo, rsync, root, lvm, rsnapshot

I'd like to cron a local backup to a locally mounted USB drive.  I'm using rsnapshot and want it to back up an LVM snapshot onto the USB drive.  But, unless I run the cron as root it complains that I can't make an LVM snapshot because I don't have permission to look at /dev/mapper/control.  Am I missing something?

This is on CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Can you provide the command you're running?

Comment: @slm `rsnapshot daily`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this topic in the CentOS wiki, titled: [rsnapshot Backups](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RsnapshotBackups). It has examples that show how to backup using rsnapshot:

*excerpt from that page*

```
# crontab -e

#MAILTO="" ##Supresses output
MAILTO=me
###################################################################
#minute (0-59),                                                   #
#|    hour (0-23),                                                #
#|    |        day of the month (1-31),                           #
#|    |        |       month of the year (1-12),                  #
#|    |        |       |       day of the week (0-6 with 0=Sunday)#
#|    |        |       |       |       commands                   #
###################################################################
15    02       *       *       *        /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot/laptop.rsnapshot.conf daily
15    03       *       *       Sun      /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot/laptop.rsnapshot.conf weekly
30    03       1       *       *        /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot/laptop.rsnapshot.conf monthly
```

I don't think you can do this as non-root, especially if you're interacting with the LVM. I found numerous tickets regarding the lack of access to LVM tools for non-root users.

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=620571

Given this the crontab entry will have to be one that's run by root.